# TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined

Tags: json, angular, typescript, mapping, angular11

I am trying to map some values of JSON response to another variable but getting some error "Cannot set property name of undefined"

```
export interface Data
{
   description: any;
   name : any;
}
```

Inside main class defined the following data

```
actionData : any;
action:Data[]=[];

getData()
  {
      this.spref.getNewData().subscribe(
        response => {
          this.actionData = response;
          for(let i=0;i<this.actionData.length;i++)
          {
             
               this.action[i].name = this.actionData[i].name;
               this.action[i].description = this.actionData[i].description;
          }
    
          })
         
        },
        error => {
          console.log('Failure: ', error);
        }
      );

   }
```

Response of actionData in this format

```
[{
description: "pqrs"
jsonType: "com.xyz.common.object.NewData"
name: "abc"
value: "xyz"
}]
```

I want action data will be stored in this format

```
[{
description: "pqrs"
name: "abc"
}]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`action[i]` is undefined if not initialized. So, before setting any properties to it you need to initialize it, like so:

```
actionData : any;
action:Data[]=[];

getData()
  {
      this.spref.getNewData().subscribe(
        response => {
          this.actionData = response;
          for(let i=0;i<this.actionData.length;i++)
          {
               this.action[i] = {
                   name: this.actionData[i].name;
                   description: this.actionData[i].description;
               }
          }
    
          })
         
        },
        error => {
          console.log('Failure: ', error);
        }
      );

   }
```

Comment: Getting error while adding those line "Type {} missing the following property 'Data' : description"

Comment: That depends on the definition of the `Data` type you are using. It's not in the code you submitted, so I can't see it. I'll modify my answer

Comment: Changing the type of action from Data[] to any works for me. But I wonder why it is not working correctly with Data[] type

Comment: Definition of data is define in Interface. Please look it once into the code

Comment: It's not working because you defined a interface called `Data`. So, all variables of type `Data` need to have all the fields in the interface.

Comment: `action` is an array of `Data` objects, and hence all objects in `action` array have to have `description` and `name`

Comment: Sorry but I want to ask one more question is there any way to make one field optional in Interface.

Comment: yeah, you would do it like so:
`
interface Data {
    optionalField?: string;
}
`